# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType while it is imported

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark SQL dependency just as a data structure already importing it but without passing the SPark context to the Scala's main method. Why I'm getting this exception?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType
```

the code:

```
package io.sekai.industry.streaming

import org.apache.spark.sql.types
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

class NonSparkSensorsGeneration {

  val schema = StructType(
    StructField("id", LongType, nullable = false) :: //always skip this if using the operator
      StructField("Energy Data", StringType, nullable = false, metadata = new types.MetadataBuilder().putString("mqtt", "ESP_02/Energy Data").putString("label", "EnergyData").build()) ::
      Nil)

  def readFromCSVFile(shortPath: String): Unit= {

    println("Preparing to load the csv file from jar resource " + shortPath)
    val input = getClass.getResourceAsStream(shortPath)
    println("Loaded file from resource " + shortPath)
    println("Input stream from resource " + shortPath + " details: " + input.toString)
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(input)
    val data = source.getLines.map(_.split("\t")).toArray
    source.close
    println(data.getClass)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    readFromCSVFile("generation")
  }
}
```

then the class is inherited from the object:

```
package io.sekai.industry.streaming

object NonSparkSensorsGenerationJob extends NonSparkSensorsGeneration
```

and ran as:

> "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-12.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\idea\20\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50417:D:\idea\20\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\eljah32\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file1955225673 .industry.streaming.NonSparkSensorsGenerationJob

It runs ok, when I just remove the      `val schema` variable

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: @GaëlJ with ``"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-12.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\idea\20\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50417:D:\idea\20\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\eljah32\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file1955225673 .industry.streaming.NonSparkSensorsGenerationJob``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to enable the `Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath` flag in your IDE (the flag I mentioned is from IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: If was done for other classes/traits and executed without any problem. So looks like the scope is the same

Comment: The problem is not with the scope but the configuration of the run. Each class that you execute should be defined separately with this flag.

Comment: I'm actually run the object that extends this class and it is run ok when the schema variable is dropped out

Comment: How do you run the object that extends it? through the IDE? if so, can you share the run configuration?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question